# Read and write emails in my app using imap/pop smtp

Tags: ios, email, ios8, swift2, email-client

I want to read emails in my app by setting **IMAP/POP** settings, and send email by setting **SMPT** setting, using swift, i am unable to find any thing for this, please help me

Comment: Where's your code? What did you try?

Comment: i had just started R&D about it, i dont even have code, but i have to implement it

Comment: Cool. As soon as you have it could you post it pls?

Comment: yeh,sure @borracciaBlu